# Jenkins / Java intermittently can't find rake using rvm plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, classpath, rvm, jenkins-plugins

This is the most annoying problem because it's intermittent.

My Jenkins task updates a Ruby/Rails repository, and runs tests on it. I'm using the RVM plugin, and the rvm-managed environment is specified and exists.

Yet periodically, the task will fail with:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake" (in directory "<http://jenkins.example.net/job/test_cms/ws/")>: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I can repeat the job run and it will succeed. The program does in fact exist at the path specified in the error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Amazingly this problem still exists nine months later. I can't tell if it's a JVM problem or a Jenkins problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the RVM plugin. I run my Jenkins server with RVM installed system-wide and Jenkins picks it up in its path. You might give that a try if you can't get your current setup fixed.